# How to refresh a form from another?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I'm working with windows form, in one form a list the data of a table and in the other one, I add the data. In the form that I list, I have the the form load to set the values of the table in a datagridview. So I want that when I click save in the saving form, I reload the other form where I list the data. I've tried something like:

```
form.refresh
```

but doesn't work. I tried closing the list form when clicking add, and then when I clicked save it would show up again, that worked, but is there other way I can do it?

Here is my code:

List form:

```
 private void ListadoExpedientes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      dgvExpedientes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
      Exp = ExpedienteNG.GetExpedientes();
      bExpedientes = new BindingList<Expediente>(Exp);
      dgvExpedientes.DataSource = bExpedientes;
 }
```

and here is the save form:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ListadoExpedientes listexp = new ListadoExpedientes();
      listexp.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: How to share data between forms is one of the more common .Net questions on SO. I suggest you do a search first, if you still have trouble come back and add relevant code to the question.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: A form is just a class. If you create a `new` instance you have a new instance, not the one that you set data on before. You will see this theme repeated if you search your problem first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Refresh a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797975/how-to-refresh-a-form-from-another-form)

Answer (score 1):

Class(Form) - Form2 (ex.) that holds the method that requires update in base form - Form1

In Form2 define constructor and a variable that holds a Form1 object

```
  Form1 frm1;
    public Form2(Form1 _frm1){ 
       InitializeComponent();
       ...
       this.frm1 = _frm1;
       this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.RefreshDatagrid);
    }
```

In Form1

```
     public void RefreshDataGrid()
            {
                dgvExpedientes.DataSource = null;
                dgvExpedientes.DataSource = bExpedientes;
            }

private void OpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 = new Form2 (this);
            t.ShowDialog();
        }
```

This code will update the dgvExpedientes in form1 , when you close the form2,
so the event is triggered after you finish uploading records and close the form2.
I hope this will help in your situation

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Application.OpenForms collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) to find your open forms.
then call refresh from there.
Example:

```
var listForm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => x.Name == "ListadoExpedientes").FirstOrDefault();
if (listForm != null)
{
    listForm.Refresh();
}
```

You might need to tweek some things, because I didn't test this.